# SFTP SSH_FXP_READ Offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, sftp

I'm writing an SFTP server in node.js, but I've run into a strange issue at the final hurdle, reading files… This is a pretty obscure topic but any help would be appreciated.

Following version 3 SFTP spec here: https://filezilla-project.org/specs/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02.txt

I've been testing the server with FileZilla, Coda2 and command line sftp on OSX. Each has been successful in all functions until reading which include some 64 bit communication, but each seems to produce a different weird behaviour when reading files.

According to the spec (section 6.4), SSH_FXP_READ should provide:

```
uint32     id <- request id
string     handle <- file handle
uint64     offset
uint32     len
```

Which all come through with a valid id and handle, but the offset and length are a different matter. I'm only using a 2 byte handle here for simplicity.

```
Coda Expected:
5 ff 0 30000
6 ff 30000 30000
7 ff 60000 30000
8 ff 90000 30000
etc until EOF

Coda Real:
5 ff 0 30000
6 ff 30000 30000
7 ff 27232 30000
8 ff 89872 30000
9 ff 87104 30000
10 ff 149872 30000
```

Coda gets the first two right but then loses it...

Now my first thought was I'd just read the 64bit offset wrong:

```
(buf.readUInt32BE(0) << 32) + buf.readUInt32BE(4)
```

Edit: Changed bitshift example to 32 from 8 (still not working), also tried node-bignum and node-int64 with identical results

Javascript's 53 bits of precision here should be enough for file sizes right?

So I verified the reading with python unpack (">Q") and was correct.
Not only that but the same 64bit handlers are communicating file sizes in SSH_FXP_READDIR and SSH_FXP_STAT just fine..

So lets try a different client, can't be worse than that right?

FileZilla doesn't actually request a length on the first chunk and will instead request whatever length the server returns on the first chunk. Regardless of the length of the returned data, the offset seems to be incremented by 65536 bytes or more…

The only thing I can think of is that reading 64bit buffer is just wrong, but even reading them by hand it's wrong:

```
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 75 30> Expected:30000 Got:30000
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 6a 60> Expected:60000 Got:27232
```

We're getting errors before it even breaks 32 bits.

Now if I ignore the offset and length completely and just stream the file to the client in chunks on each read request and serve an EOF status when complete, it works fine in all clients. But obviously this disregards the spec so is a bad idea.

Unfortunately there isn't much relevant code to post as this seems like a pretty fundamental problem.

Any ideas or insight would be much appreciated.
At this point I don't even care if its an elementary mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's bitwise operators only work in 32-bit values. So what you can do instead is simply use multiplication/division, which is what I do in my sftpv3 client in [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/e6198aa575deed479bccae89e21964aa48540ad4/lib/SFTP/SFTPv3.js#L1094-L1105).

Also just to point out, `(buf.readUInt32BE(0) << 8)` would only be shifting the 4 bytes 1 byte to the left instead of 4 in order to make room for the other 4 bytes of the 64-bit integer.